# Network : Linux can't connect to specific site

Tags: linux, networking

I have a local network connected to internet, and several computers. The Windows machines are working just fine, but all the Linux machines (VMs or hard) can't connect to one specific site (on any port/service, including 80/443/22 etc.). They are based on Ubuntu 16.04 (kubuntu for the most part).

The rest of the sites are working fine. DNS requests are working fine and yield the right address.

Just **this specific IP** address doesn't work, and **only on Linux**. For all the services tested, the result is always the same : they can't connect to the server. The problem happened sporadically but is now more extreme. It's also probably not a firewall rule (since it used to work without changes in any firewall).

How can I diagnose such a problem?

Comment: subnet mask more restrictive? vpn? have a route?

Comment: Mask `255.255.255.0`. No VPN. Command `ip route get <remote_ip>` yields `<remote_ip> via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0  src 192.168.1.40 
    cache` (on several lines).

Comment: Got a tcpdump/wireshark? Your `ip route get` is a good start, but if packets mysteriously differ in behavior, actually _looking_ at them will help a lot. (I would almost bet on the site dropping packets with TCP ECN...)

Comment: There it disappeared again... Without any action... I will post updates when it happens again sorry :(